# Sharepoint Nintex Workflow 2010 Create Item With Lookup Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lookup, nintex-workflow, createitem

I am having troubles while trying to create an item in a list when it has a lookup field. That is:

- Let my list be A and let it have a lookup field to the list B.
- Let my item A1 in the workflow contain the item B1 in the B field.

I am trying to create an item A2 in a workflow of A1, and I want the B field be B1, just same as A1.

What I do is, just use "Create Item" step, and set B column to Current Item -> B

However, I get the error "Serverwas unable to process request. ---> Failed to publish workflow: Validation failed: Path resolved to Referenced activityProperty 'ReturnValu' whose Preperty Type 'System.String' does not match with the Target Type 'System.Int32'"

I suppose it tries to tell me that, I can't just use reference of an item while using it in create steps. However, I tried to cast it to Lookup ID (as integer), Lookup Value (as integer) as well and none worked.

So, my question is, how to succeed in this item create step?

Answer (score 0):

The lookup field needs to set using the **List Lookup** option when assigning values, e.g. for a lookup field entitled Request being assigned the value of the current item:

[image: Set Field Value using List Lookup]